# WordPress Hacked - Found a suspicious "class-wp-style-table.php"

Tags: php, webserver, wordpress

I recently had all of my WordPress accounts on my server hacked. The only suspicious files I found are listed below. These were the only files edited in the last 5 days (June 3, to be specific).

Suspicious files found:

- **`/host.txt`** - This file only had the wordpress installed domain name in text (e.g.: `example.com`)
- **`/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-style-table.php`** - This is a nasty one. See sample of the code in [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/wQt4G4ab).

How can I detect where these files came from to prevent them from being regenerated? I searched Google, and there are `0` hits for this file name. Is this a new WP attack?

***UPDATE*** 
I found an exact replica of the malicious file in a Joomla install called "mod_googleapi.php". I think this is the source of my breach. It's a dated install of Joomla that must have some leaky extensions/plugins.

Comment: Seems to be same as this -http://news.nucleusdevelopment.com/2013/03/14/wordpress-toolbox-exploit/

Comment: And this - http://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/threat/encyclopedia/entry.aspx?Name=Backdoor%3APHP%2FShell.G and https://www.google.com/search?q=backdoor+PHP%3A%3A%2FShell.G+Wordpress

Comment: I'm curious how come you didn't find any results for this filename on Google? It's part of the WordPress installation and the original and intended version of it is [published on GitHub](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php). Anyway, the contents that you're posting (I've removed your image with the link to pastebin) and the contents of the original file are obviously quite substantially different, but the one you're posting looks rather strange for a backdoor (not saying that it isn't), as it's even got an easy to use control interface.

Comment: you're looking at "class-wp-list-table.php" no "class-wp-style-table.php". the style-table.php is not standard code. it is completely malicious.

Comment: Interestingly, it uses a non-salted hash to verify the access password. If it helps in any way, the password (cracked from the md5 hash `7e9424bfa12d1f2ad32463ac1a80e407`) is `4500045`. I'm posting this, because it can be easily cracked by matching it to a precompiled md5 hash table [even online](http://crackstation.net/) within a split second. Posting passwords is otherwise unacceptable, but this one is really a no-brainer and might help you gain access to its interface and see for yourself what needs to be done to thwart against any reinfestation. The interface will be to your WP only!

Comment: Ah yes, I indeed made a mistake with my Google search there. Well, doesn't matter, just ignore that part of my comment. I was still able to find a pastebin for it (I imagine yours?) that I added to your question. It makes it easier to inspect the code. ;)

Comment: Yes, that was my pastebin :0 however, when i open the shortlink, my anti-virus warns me against it!

Comment: How can I use that password to learn more about this attack?

Comment: Ideally, you wouldn't do that on a production server (despite being already infected) but in a sandboxed local installation that has no internet connection and only a very limited access to much anything else. It's not required anyway and since the code is quite straightforwardly written, it's probably best to inspect what it's doing and where through it. I'm now reading through the code and can't tell yet, if there will be anything revealing in it about how your server got infected in the first place. I wouldn't bet on it though. You should better go through your logs for any signs of it.

Comment: It would be also helpful, if you could include more information on your server's setup. Are you running a FTP/SFTP/SSH? How do you connect to them? What OS, web server software, packages installed? HTTP/HTTPS? Anything revealing in your server's log files about this infection? Database? ... Basically, anything you can think of and might help us determine, what made this infection possible and how to prevent it from happening again. The `.php` file though seems to be collecting password files from filesystem, databases and services, and is capable of brute-forcing them using your own CPU.

Comment: Wow,  yet another hacked Wordpress site.  This is probably the 100th post on security.se for this.

Comment: @Rook - Sure, but this is a new shell, I suggest you read through its code, if you find the time. It's packed full with _goodies_. I don't think this question is too localized, even if it's a specific threat, there won't be this single instance of it, that's for sure.

Comment: @TildalWave I think it's too-localized in that the core question is "what happened *in this particular instance*". What's in this shell that you don't find in r57, c99, et.al.?

Comment: @tylerl - Yeah good point. Tho I was leaning more towards _not a real question_ because of lack of details (that I requested from OP in one of the previous comments). I've only been analyzing the shell because I found it interesting (not often that we see them without much code obfuscation and still pretty complete), but actually wanted to concentrate on the second part of the question (which is of course a duplicate of many other similar questions with _nuke it from orbit_ recommendation anyway). Still, I got to prepare a new _nuke it_ meme pic. ;)

Comment: @TildalWave if you want to see some popular shells in their original form, look at r57(dot)gen(dot)tr. At your own risk, of course, and probably using links or another invulnerable browser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your server was infected with a PHP backdoor trojan that goes by these names:

```
a-squared: Backdoor.PHP.Shell!IK
AVAST!: VBS:Malware-gen
AVG: PHP/BackDoor
BitDefender: Trojan.Php.Backdoor.APF
ClamAV: PHP.Shell-38
Dr.Web: PHP.Shell.26
F-Secure: Trojan.Php.Backdoor.APF [Aquarius]
GData: Trojan.Php.Backdoor.APF [Engine:A]
Ikarus: Backdoor.PHP.Shell
Kaspersky: Backdoor.PHP.PhpShell.dd
Microsoft: Backdoor:PHP/Shell.G
NOD32: PHP/WebShell.NAH trojan
nProtect: Trojan.Php.Backdoor.APF
```

It is currently detected by [roughly 38% of AV scanners that VirSCAN.org tracks](http://r.virscan.org/077c851a5905ecbfca359ea37e2be670). The way to test your AV for this exploit is simply by opening [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/wQt4G4ab) and trying to download it as a file. Your AV should detect it, notify you of malware under one of those names from above, and deny download. If it's not detected, simply delete the downloaded file. Your system won't be infected, unless you run it through a PHP interpreter on your web server.

I've been reading the exploit's code, and frankly, it's pretty scary stuff and one of the most complete shells I've ever seen. Here are a few things it can do:

- **`Read`, `Edit`, `Overwrite`** any file the web application process it runs in will have access to.
- **`Extract from`, `Compress to`** ZIP and TAR archives (can inject itself into existing archives)
- **`Brute-force FTP, MySQL, PostgreSQL`** access using web server's own CPU
- **`Scripted interface`** for easy remote C&C shell control
- **`POST requests for everything`** to hide from simpler WAF and avoid detection by web server rules
- **`Complete Database Control`** including SQL shorthands for most common injections
- **`Automated password and shadow file extraction`** for offline password extraction/cracking
- **`File System Access Control`** including rewriting access permissions on files, directories
- **`Enable / Disable reporting services`** to avoid detection through log files
- **`Self-Destruction Mechanism`** to perform cleanup after other backdoors are installed
- **`Password and cookie token protected`** to prevent easy sandboxed inspection of its functions (albeit the protection scheme is pretty weak, see my comment to the question)
- **`e.t.c.`**

Presume all your data, file system, operating system, everything infected and other backdoors installed to them. Presume all your passwords stolen, password and shadow files packed and downloaded. This is not a joke!

## Sometimes, all you can do is...

[image: Nuke It From orbit!]

## It's the only way to be sure.

So what can you do? Like the image suggests, nuke it from orbit. Start from a clean slate and restore from a known good offline backup, before this exploit happened:

- Format the drive and reinstall OS, any other software you'll need, keep them updated
- Assume all your installation files infected / out of date and download latest versions
- Rethink what software packages you really need, and how you could harden remote access
- If you don't have it yet, install a SSL certificate on your web server, use encrypted access protocols on everything
- Reassess firewall rules, deny traffic on all ports you won't be using, inbound and outbound
- Install a good antivirus software and update its virus definitions regularly both on your server and on all clients that you'll be accessing your server from, enable heuristic scanning, regularly perform full system scan
- Never access your web server remotely from an untrusted location and/or unsecured connection like public access points for administration purposes
- Secure access to your CMS/panel software folders, files, URLs, password protect everything
- Assume all your passwords stolen, including passwords of any users of your online services
- Restore from an offline backup from before the date of the infection
- Inspect all restored from backup files and database records for injections, trojans, backdoors,...
- Write support code in your online services to demand password change for all your users and deny access before they do
- Notify all your users their passwords might have been compromised and they ought to change their passwords for any other third-party services they might use them for too
- Run each domain on your server from a separate VM and assign as limiting privileges to their processes as you can live with, lock files and database access permissions
- Hire an IT security consultant to assess vulnerability of your server and services it's running, act according to consultant's recommendation
- Assume I've forgotten to include something in this list, and find more information and recommendations to a similar scenario on this and other websites that you trust

Best of luck!